# Disable default logging in /opt/engine.log

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

I have a Spring Boot app with many sub frameworks. When I start the app I get by default logging in `/opt/engine.log`. Is there some way to disable globally this logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can redirect the log in different ways.

1. You can add in the .properties file `logging.file=/path/to/your/logfile.log` or, in the yaml file
   `logging: file: /path/to/your/logfile.log`
2. If your application uses logback, add to logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="/path/to/your/logfile.log"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>
    <root level="OFF">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

3. If your application uses log4j2, add to log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="/path/to/your/logfile.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="OFF">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**UPDATED:**

You can set the root logger level to OFF or ERROR to disable logging. For that you can modify your logback.yml file.

```
logger:
    - name: ROOT
      level: OFF
```

And also you can disable logging for a specific appender

```
appender:
    - name: FILE
      enabled: false
```

Comment: how I can disable the logging using `logback.yml` file?

Comment: I've updated the post, keep an eye on it.